# How to create facebook app invited with an external application?

Tags: facebook, api, sdk

I know how to retrieve data from facebook GRAPH (such as app requests, etc) but what I am wondering how to do, is allow an application to create a facebook application request via http/https (not using the actual facebook dialouge)

Is there a backend system to allow apps (with perhaps id and security token info) to manually create application invites so that an app can use its own UI for invitations? (I've seen it done in other apps so I know there has to be some sort of way to do it)

An example of an app I've seen this done is the sims social, where you select your friends all from their UI, then a dialouge pops up that has all their names and the text for the invite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is their UI doing the friend selecting and its passing thru to the Send Dialog/UI element. With a bit of clever tracking stuck on it.

I'm assuming the second dialog is a Facebook Dialog?

I don't think you can use your own UI for the actual invitation. At some point in order to send it you have to have popped a Facebook UI element via the Javascript API. Its part of keeping Facebook looking like Facebook, since you are in their walled Garden.

In short.
You can't.
You have to use a Facebook Dialog to contact Facebook users, whether this is an App invite or a Send Dialog.

Check the docs here for the Invite Dialog.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

You can pass it a bunch of Facebook People ID's to send to.

Comment: When I use the TO paramater to use more than one ID it gives and error saying too many recipients were selected, how do I pass multiple IDs to the UI? Thanks for your response!

Comment: I believe its comma separated, the link has no sample code, and I don't have any to hand to test with. Post your code so we can look at it as well

Comment: I've been using FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', to: 'ID1, ID2, ID3', message: 'Message Data.', data: 'tracking information for the user'}); but i get the error that too many recipients are selected.